# Test that deals with time, selecting a time 1 hour ahead of test run

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

In a test I have to automate, I have to fill out a time drop down selection. The catch is that I have to select a time that is 1 hour after the test has created the event. My question is simply:

> Is there a method in selenium that can actively get the current time of the test run?
>
> Can I use that data to pick the correct time from the drop down?

If anyone has any suggestion on this matter I would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: Can't you use C# to get the current system date/time?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addhours.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selenium does not deal with current or future time. But the language you use to write selenium test does. Selenium is just one of the libraries available in your language of choice. Date/time library (and other libraries) are imported in the same way Selenium/webdriver is.

Answer (score 1):

For your specific case, I would try the following:

```
DateTime.Now.AddHours(1.00).ToString("HH:mm:ss")
```

You add an hour to the current time (and date). Then, you convert it to the format you want for later use in your datepicker.
As an alternative to `Now` you can use some other properties like `Hour` and `Minute` if that suits your datepicker input better.

See the [DateTime documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime) for more details.